# In New York, how long does a 16-year-old have to get new working papers?

Tags: new-york-state, labor-law

Say a worker is approaching his 16th birthday. Is there a grace period to get the required new working papers?  If not, is it possible to get the new working papers while the person is still 15?  How close to their birthday does it have to be?

The only thing I found is:

> When you turn 16, you will need to go from your 14-15 year old working papers (blue) and get your 16-17 year old working papers (green)

However, that doesn't cover grace periods, or information about updating papers when school isn't in session.